# show progress indicator in windows phone when System.Tray is not visible

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, progress-indicator

i want to show progress indicator in my windows phone app when System.Tray is not visible (my app is full screen). is there a simple way to show the progress indicator?

Comment: Could you please add a screen shot of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `ProgresBar` control which gives you the same result when you put it on the top of your layout? It's easy to use and looks exactly the same.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <!-- Your controls are here -->

    <ProgressBar x:Name="MyProgressBar" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 IsIndeterminate="True" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the benefit of showing `SystemTray` - you can use it for status messages and progress. If you choose not to use `SystemTray`, you have to add `ProgressBar` to the xaml of your Pages.

Comment: i find a solution . i set visibility of the  `SystemTray` To True and set Background of it to transparent and opacity to 0. every thing in `SystemTray` is hidden except Time. i want to hide the time portion but i don't find any solution for it

Comment: @SoheilGhahremani but the `SystemTray` still takes space. Isn't the progress indicator hidden too?